# Proof that $(\frac{z}{\bar{z}})^2$ has no limit when $z\to0$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

> Proof that $(\frac{z}{\bar{z}})^2$ has no limit when $z\to0$.

I have been struggling understanding the proof for this problem. The exersise says I should use the case that $z=(0,y)$ and $z=(x,x)$.

Indeed,
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(x,0)} (\frac{z}{\bar{z}})^2=1 \neq \lim_{(x,y)\to(x,x)} (\frac{z}{\bar{z}})^2=-1$$

But I am not entirely sure why the situation $z=(x,x)$ is relevant. Could anyone give me a hint here?

Comment: $z=(x,x)$ is not specifically relevant. You could use $z=(ax,bx)$ and let $x\to 0$ for any $(a,b)$ with $a\ne0$ and $b\ne 0$. $a=b=1$ seems to be the simplest way to do so though

Comment: Proof simply says for limit to exist it should be same irrespective of path chosen for $z$ to approach 0. But for path along real-axis $(y=0)$ and along line $y=x$, the limit values differ.

Comment: The formula $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(x,x)} (\frac{z}{\bar{z}})^2$$ is quite badly formed. Please, more notational rigor...

Comment: There is nothing inherently special about $z = (x,x)$ The point is that, as you approach (0,0) from different directions, you get different limits.

Answer (score 3):

Using the polar representation you can see that $\left(\frac{z}{\bar z}\right)^2=\left(\frac{re^{i\theta}}{re^{-i\theta}}\right)^2=(e^{2i\theta})^2=e^{4i\theta}$, so the result of this function depends on $\theta$ and is constant along lines with a constant $\theta$, since all of these lines intersect in the origin ($z=0$) it is sufficient to find two lines (or, equivalently, two values of $\theta$) giving different results.

The simplest choices of going along the axes (imaginary or real, from either direction) happen to all give the same result in this case, so you get the hint telling you to try a different direction.

Answer (score 1):

When working with real numbers, you must check that both left and right limits are the same. With complex numbers, the analog to both sides is every direction. So, you are given an example of two directions where the limits differ, meaning that the limit doesnt exist.